# E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$1 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: android, google-play-services, classnotfoundexception, unmarshalling

i have one problem on app run time

**Logcat**:

> **E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$1
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:** com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$1
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2843)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2700)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067)
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086)
>           at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7718)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:473)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:424)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1314)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6180)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6032)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:121)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3973)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$1
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1355)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1415)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
>           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2843) 
>           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797) 
>           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2700) 
>           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067) 
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257) 
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086) 
>           at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7718) 
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:473) 
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:424) 
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1314) 
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6180) 
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6032) 
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:121) 
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3973) 
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: add some more detail.

Comment: During call on Google play subscription i got run time error on this